# submit a form after authenticating another form

Tags: javascript, forms

Here I'm having two HTML forms.
**Login Form**

```
<form name="login" method=post action="http://xxxx.com/auth.asp">  
<input type=hidden id=UserName name="userid" value="xxxxx"></input> 
<input type=hidden id=Password name="password" value="yyyyyy"></input> 
</form>
```

**Another form**

```
<form name="action" method=post action="http://xxxxxx.com/user/xxxxx.asp">  
<input type=hidden id=UserName name="xxxxxx" value="xxxxx"></input> 
<input type=hidden id=Password name="yyyyyy" value="yyyyy"></input> 
</form>
```

I can able to submit my 1st form by just calling

```
document.login.submit()
```

But after the above statement is performed, any code below it is not getting executed.
I have to execute the following code after the above mentioned code:

```
document.action.submit()
```

Comment: Are your forms on the same page?

Comment: Yes. Both these forms are in the same page..

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting the form without ajax, the browser to perform a redirect or page refresh. This will cause the rest of the javascript to stop executing.